# Increasing the Voltage Output of a Solar Cell

Tags: voltage, solar-cell, charger

I'm working on a project where I'm going to charge a battery using a solar cell. The cell is capable of outputting a maximum of 4 A, but only 0.5 volts (2W).

My question is, how can I charge the battery with only one cell? I understand I'll have to step up the voltage in some way, but I'm not sure how. I read that I can use boost converters, but don't these need a steady voltage for them to work properly? The solar cell probably won't be outputting its max voltage output all the time.

Ideally, I can regulate the voltage output of the cell to something like 2.4 volts (a single battery is rated at 1.2 volts).

Comment: What kind of battery are you wanting to charge?  When you say "a single battery is rated at 1.2 volts" does that mean that is the voltage that the battery needs to be charging?

Comment: Yes. The battery is a rechargeable AA battery.

Comment: Charging from such low voltage sources I believe falls under "energy harvesting". One such IC here: http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/7183

Comment: That sounds like quite a large single cell; is there a reason why you have to use only one cell, rather than a more usual arrangement with a stack of 4 or 5?

Comment: Search on "Joule Thief" for some example circuits. They will need some interesting re-engineering to handle 4 amps though!

Comment: It is indeed one big cell. The biggest problem is the cost - The costed like 14 or so bucks, so getting some more will be costly. After looking at the other solutions, I think my best bet is to try getting my hands on a different cell. Thank you very much for your suggestions, gentlemen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few boost controllers that run down that low, but in general it's better to have a higher voltage to start with. 0.5V at full tilt is really low, presumably it's designed to be stacked to get a usable voltage.

[Here's](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3105) an example of one of the very low input voltage boost converters. Of course this one doesn't do much current, so it doesn't really fit the bill...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't do much current"? I thought a dc-dc converter works by stepping up the voltage at the expense of the current. Wouldn't a high current rating for the cell be better in this case?

Comment: That particular device is limited to 400ma. In general, high current = high resistive losses, hence the distribution of power at extremely high voltage.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.